# Number of submatrix of size AxB in a matrix of size MxN

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I am following https://taninamdar.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/submatrices3.pdf  to find total number of sub matrix of a matrix.But am stuck how to find how many sub matrix of a given size is present in a matrix.
Also 0<=A<=M and 0<=B<=N.
where AxB(submatrix size) and MxN(matrix size).

Comment: The answer is `C(M, A) * C(N, B)`, where `C(X, Y)` is the binomial coefficient, i.e. `C(X, Y) = X! / (Y! (X - Y)!)`.

Comment: If we consider first matrix as 3X3 then number of submatrix of size 2X2 will be only 4.But by your answer I am getting 9.

Comment: Apparently they must be contiguous submatrixes, the pdf neglects to mention that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't go through the pdf (math and I aren't friends), however simple logic is enough here. Simply, try to reduce the dimension: How many vectors of length `m` can you put in a vector of length `n` ?

Answer: `n-m+1`. To convince you, just go through the cases. Say `n = 5` and `m = 5`. You've got one possibility. With `n = 5` and `m = 4`, you've got two (second vector starts at index 0 or index 1). With `n = 5` and `m = 3`, you've got three (vector can start at index 0, 1 or 2). And for `n = 5` and `m = 1`, you've got 5, seems logic.

So, in order to apply that to a matrix, you have to add a dimension. How do you do that ? Multiplication. How many vectors of length `a` can you put inside a vector of length `n` ? `n-a+1`. How many vectors of length `b` can you put inside a vector of length `m` ? `m-b+1`.

So, how many matrices of size `A*B` can you put in a matrix of length `N*M` ? `(N-A+1)*(M-B+1)`.

So, I didn't handle the case where one of the dimension is 0. It depends on how you consider this case.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it.